# How does the reshape work before the fully connected layer in the following CNN model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Consider the convolutional neural network (two convolutional layers):

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(7*7*32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

The fully connected layer `fc` is to have `7*7*32` inputs coming in. The above:

`out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)` leads to a tensor with size of `(32, 49)`.
This doesn't seem right as the dimensions of input for the dense layer is different. What am I missing here?

[Note that in Pytorch the input is in the following format: [N, C, W, H] so no. of channels comes before the width and height of image]

***source***: https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/convolutional_neural_network/main.py#L35-L56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output of each layer you can easily understand what you are missing.

```
def forward(self, x):
    print ('input', x.size())
    out = self.layer1(x)
    print ('layer1-output', out.size())
    out = self.layer2(out)
    print ('layer2-output', out.size())
    out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
    print ('reshape-output', out.size())
    out = self.fc(out)
    print ('Model-output', out.size())
    return out

test_input = torch.rand(4,1,28,28)
model(test_input)

OUTPUT:

('input', (4, 1, 28, 28))   
('layer1-output', (4, 16, 14, 14))  
('layer2-output', (4, 32, 7, 7))  
('reshape-output', (4, 1568))  
('Model-output', (4, 10))
```

Conv2d layer doesn't change the height and width of the tensor. only changes the channel of tensor because of stride and padding. MaxPool2d layer halves the height and width of the tensor.

```
inpt    = 4,1,28,28  
conv1_output = 4,16,28,28  
max_output   = 4,16,14,14  
conv2_output = 4,32,14,14  
max2_output  = 4,32,7,7  
reshapeutput = 4,1585 (32*7*7)  
fcn_output   = 4,10
```

**N** --> Input Size, **F** --> Filter Size, **stride**-> Stride Size, **pdg**-> Padding size

ConvTranspose2d;

**OutputSize = N*stride + F - stride - pdg*2**

Conv2d;

**OutputSize = (N - F)/stride + 1 + pdg*2/stride** [e.g. 32/3=10 it ignores after the comma]

Comment: ohh I somehow totally forgot that I could have printed each layers output! my bad. Thank you for the explanation! @Salih can you also tell me why the `padding=2` works like the `same` padding in TensorFlow?

Comment: The Conv_layer output formula [ OUTPUT = (N-F)/stride + 1 + p*2 ]   N->inputsize F-> kernel size p-> padding count. padding expands the input layer.

Comment: For example, your input (15,15,3) and padding=3, program puts three-shape(fills with zeros or ones) borders to input. your new input is (21,21,3)

Comment: Okay, the Conv_layer output formula can be used to calculate padding for `same` configuration. It comes out to be **p = (F-1)/2**, for `stride = 1`. Thanks, really helped with my network.